# Amazon S3 file control of expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $key
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+48 hours');
```

Let's say I have one file name "policy.doc", Im using this code to create direct link in 48 hours for 2 users.

The problem is when 1 user quit and I don't want him can access this file anymore, while the other user can access as usual.
How can I control and make the one who quit cannot access this file?

Comment: What do you mean by quit?  Logout?

Comment: hi Kannaiyan, quit mean those user will never access this file again, will be delete